# bring data from a JSON and show in a popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a leaderboard where if you click on a name a popup is displayed : https://jsfiddle.net/pvwvdgLn/1/

In practice, I will pull the list of the leaderboard from a DB.What you see here in the list are static names of employees,just for reference. So,how do I assign names using data attributes and search for that name in the JSON?

There are various fields in the popup like: Name,Email,Date of birth etc which I want to display for the respective person whose name is clicked by the user.

I have below JSON which is fetching me the array which contains all these data of all the people in the list :

```html
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "xxxxx";
$connectioninfo = array(
    'Database' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectioninfo);
if (!$conn) {
    echo 'connection failure';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}

$q1 = "select top 10 *
from pointsBadgeTable
WHERE WeekNumber ='week51'
order by pointsRewarded desc";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $q1);
if ($stmt == false) {
    echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}
do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

//Set content type to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Echo a json object to the browser
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

As can be seen in the query,it fetches JSON for all the top10 ,whose names can be seen in the list.

the html and JS related to the popup is here : https://jsfiddle.net/woef5mn6/

**How can I display the respective data in the popup from the JSON only for the person whose name is clicked ?**

please help me.

Comment: Please rewrite your snippet into a [mcve] - the snippet does not run PHP and if your AJAX works, post only HTML, JS and JSON

Comment: Yes this is possible, **Please rewrite your snippet into a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - the snippet does not run PHP and if your AJAX works, post only HTML, JS and JSON**

Comment: @mplungjan I tried my best to give you guys the entire snippet.The issue is, the names in the list is static as I cannot include the DB related info here.The fiddle wont take php i guess.The JS and html is already in the above fiddle.you can copy it locally.Thanks for the input.God bless.

Comment: Could you please post the JSON data ?

Comment: Just view-source for the HTML, then strip out unnecessary stuff and replace the names in a few lines of JSON for fictitious ones

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  wasup... you want something precise.

Comment: I see no JSON in any of your posts or JSFiddles

Comment: Yes, just create a simple demo fiddle with minimum data and give the link

Comment: just a min.. i will get back

Comment: @mplungjani will include the json file too

Comment: also @mplungjan the names in the list comes form a query which I am echoing.Its not related to the JSOn.The JSON is only for the popup's data.

Comment: @mplungjan here is the JSON for just one employee :[{"ReportingManager":"Bob Percival","EmployeeName":"Brandon Barnes","WeekNumber":"week51","WeeklyHoursLogged":47,"EmployeeID":2164,"pointsRewarded":120,"Comment":"Employee submitted above 40 hours for the week - per hour extra 10 points","rank":13,"Gold":1,"silver":0,"bronze":0,"LevelField":2.55319,"intoTheGame":1,"Completionist":1,"beyondTheCallOfDuty":0,"Slacker":0,"goGetter":0,"energetic":0,"MngrEmpId":null,"RisingStar":null,"Armageddon":null}]

Comment: @MayankPandeyz here is the json

Comment: @VishwaKumar I have given a JSON for one employee

Comment: OK, so you want some value to be shown from this JSON?

Comment: I want to pull some of the above JSON fields in the popup

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yeah

Comment: OK, so what is the problem you are facing in this?

Comment: I tried to pull data in the popup using this https://jsfiddle.net/23aupwxb/ .The point is the data should be displayed only for the person whose name is clicked.

Comment: I am unable to find a way to do so . @MayankPandeyz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133428/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-jane).

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your fiddle to show how your problem can be solved. This is just a simple solution. It needs to modified according to your requirement.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ewogt0r/2/)

I am creating the employee list from your JSON and populating the ordered list

```
function employeeList() {
        $("#myOL").empty();
    $.each(employee, function(i,o) {
          $("#myOL").append("<li><mark>" + o.EmployeeName + "</mark><small>" + o.score + "</small></li>");
    });
}
```

Then onclick of the individual employee, i am getting his details from JSON by his name and then populating the popup details (as a best practice here - you should get the employee details by calling a service through ajax using a unique identifier [employeeId] ):

```
function getEmployeeByName(name) {
    var index = -1;
  var filteredObj = employee.find(function(item, i) {
    if(item.EmployeeName === name){
      index = i;
    }
  });

  return employee[index];
}
```

Hope this helps!